# How to login windows azure using google plus details?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, azure

Hi I am new to `windows azure` ios sdk, I need to `login` to the windows azure using `google plus` details. I am getting google plus details and sending access token to windows azure, but i am getting `error` like

> Error Domain=com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorDomain
>   Code=-1301 "The server returned an error." UserInfo=0x7fc57b10ae70
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=The server returned an error.}

My code is:

```
appDelegate.client.loginWithProvider("google", token: ["access_token": authResult.accessToken], completion: { (user, error) -> Void in

   println("user====\(user)")
   println("error====\(error)")

})
```

Please help me, it's killing my time.

Comment: is it just with google? have you tried other auth providers?

Comment: I need for google and facebook, I tried with facebook also but getting same error.